# Do something when touch event was not consumed by a child

Tags: android

I have a moderately complex layout with several clickable elements. When the user clicks on an empty space or on a passive element (for example `TextView`) I want to hide the ActionBar. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        view.getRootView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 // hide action bar
            }
        });
```